# How to change state in one page from a link click from another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I change a state in a different page when a user clicks a link that takes them to that page?

for example

**hompage**

```
<Link href="/about">
  <button>click to go to about page</button>
</Link>
```

The user clicks the link in the homepage, then when the user gets to the about page, the state in the about page changes from **false** to **true** because the user clicked the link in the homepage.

**about** page

```
const [questionone, setQuestionone] = useState(false)
```

The framework is Next.js.

Comment: do you use general state management like "redux"?

Comment: You can pass a `query` attribute in your `Link` tag in the homepage like this - `<Link href={{ pathname: '/about', query: { from: 'homepage' } }}>`, and then you can use it in the about page by accessing the `query` attribute using `useRouter` like this - `const params = useRouter(); console.log(params.query.from);`, now you can utilise this value or an alternative will be to store a variable in `localStorage` and accessing it in the about page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create structure code like this:

You must create `Route` like i was create in `App.js` below:

`App.js`

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Homepage from "./Homepage";
import About from "./About";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And then you create `Homepage.jsx` component like this below, in this case you don't need to import `Link` and use `Link` for changing the path of your router, in this case i use `useHistory` to change the path of router and send a `state` to the component of the path of route in this case `/about` which is the component is `About.jsx`:

`Homepage.jsx`

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Homepage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          history.push({
            pathname: "/about",
            state: { clickedFromHome: true }
          });
        }}
      >
        click to go to about page
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

In `About.jsx` you can consume state from `Homepage` to change our `state` `questionone` in `About` Component. Example code in below:

`About.jsx`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const About = () => {
  const [questionone, setQuestionone] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.state?.clickedFromHome) {
      setQuestionone(true);
    }
  }, [location.state?.clickedFromHome]);
  console.log(location.state?.clickedFromHome);
  return <div>About{questionone.toString()}</div>;
};

export default About;
```

and now the state is changed in `About.jsx` if you click the button from Homepage to change path into '/about'

Comment: Next.js uses its own [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), you shouldn't be using `react-router-dom`. See [Migrating from React Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router).

Comment: oh i forgot this is next.js

Answer (score 0):

In react we need to use to attribute instead of href in Link tag
Your tag should like this .

```
<Link to="/about">
  <button>click to go to about page</button>
</Link>
```